# Error in inclusion of <QNetworkAccessManager>,<QNetworkReply> in cpp file of a BB10 app development

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am currently working on BB10 app development and trying for some HTTP connection demo app.

But in the cpp file is giving a `?` in front of inclusion statement `#include <QNetworkAccessManager>` saying `Unresolved Inclusion : <QNetworkAccessManager>`.

Anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`QNetworkAccessManager` comes with the QtNetwork module. You could do this: `#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>`, which should compile. However, it will not link, you need to link to QtNetwork. To achieve this, you should tell QMake that you're using QtNetwork. Add this to your `.pro` project file: `QT += network`.

This has two effects: first, the compiler will look for include files in the QtNetwork subdirectory too (so you don't need to include `<QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>`, `<QNetworkAccessManager>` will work just fine). Secondly, the linker will link to QtNetwork too. So everything will work just fine.

You can read more about using Qt modules [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-qt-libraries).